# How do exchanges like ShapeShift, Changelly or Evercoin cope with KYC/AML regulation?

Tags: legal, money-laundering, aml, financial-regulations, know-your-customer

They don't require any information about their users. Most of the exchanges require user identification: so even though exchanges like ShapeShift might have corporate account on the large exchanges like Bittrex, Poloniex, Binance, shouldn't they disclose users' info to these large exchanges?

Comment: I don't think they should disclose the users' info because what they are doing is something close to arbitrage. They have created a market where they can buy low and then sell high and vice-versa. The will only make orders on the large exchanges when the money pool for some coin goes too low. I don't think there is a 1:1 relationship between orders on shapeshift and orders on the large exchanges.